# How to remove projection in terminal from .shp file with valid .prj available

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, d3, topojson

I have .prj, .shp, .sbn, .sbx, .shx, .dbf files where the content of the .prj file is the following:

```
PROJCS["S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North",GEOGCS["GCS_S_JTSK",DATUM["D_S_JTSK",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Krovak"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1",78.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["Azimuth",30.28813975277778],PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",24.83333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",49.5],PARAMETER["X_Scale",-1.0],PARAMETER["Y_Scale",1.0],PARAMETER["XY_Plane_Rotation",90.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I would like to generate a topojson file which is not projected so I will be able to define the projection in d3. How should I parametrize topojson in Terminal to remove projection?

Comment: Have you tried `topojson -o outpu.json input.shp`? As per the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) this should work without hassle.

Comment: Yes, I tried it already but it is still projected somehow... the generated topojson file has a quite extreme transform property: "transform":{"scale":[10.652150879211582,10.765770152911628],"translate":[-591299.2230000049,-1334760.1630000025]}

Comment: Run ogr2ogr first with -s_srs EPSG:5514 -t_srs EPSG:4156. The data will now be lat-lon on S-JTSK. If you want WGS84 try using EPSG:4326 for the output instead.